# When do we change back the ark-cover etc from white to the rest-of-the-year colour?

Tags: calendar, color, simchat-torah, ark-aron-kodesh, aseres-yemei-teshuva

When do we change back the proches (ark-cover) etc from white to the rest-of-the-year colour? 
I would have thought right after Simchas Torah or possibly Isru Chag?

Comment: I would have thought before Shmini Atzeret. ימים נוראים end by _Hoshana Raba_.

Comment: @JNF So 13 Tishrei is a Yom Nora?

Comment: When do we change it _to_ white?

Comment: @DoubleAA, We usually change it to white before _Rosh Hashana_. And yes, we are _noheg_ to have honey on the table (instead or beside the salt) until _Hoshana Raba_ (when the _kvitlach_ are sent).

Answer (score 5):

Nitey Gavriel ([Rosh Hashana pg. 153](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46450&st=&pgnum=155&hilite=)) brings the custom to have white *paroches* etc until after Yom Kippur. In Nitey Gavriel ([Sukkos pg. 362](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46442&st=&pgnum=362&hilite=)) he brings the Maharil, Sharey Efrayim and Minhagei Amsterdam who say to put up white *paroches* etc. on Hashana Rabba - implying that they had already been changed back from Rosh Hashana. However he writes (without citing a source) that the custom of many Chassidic communities is to leave the white *paroches* up from Rosh Hashana till after Simchas Torah, and that some even have the custom to do so till after Shabbos Breishis.

In the Lubavitcher Rebbe's shul the white *paroches* were up from Rosh Hashana till after Simchas Torah (although Luach Kollel Chabad it says to change the *paroches* and *sifrei torah* covers to white on the days when Tefillas Tal and Tefilas Geshem are recited, implying they were not left as such from Rosh Hashana). ([Otzar Minhagei Chabad pg 363](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30510&st=&pgnum=377))