# When is the end of the Tishrei holiday "season"?

Tags: minhag, calendar

(Inspired by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20695/5))

I'm curious if there is any discussion on when the Tishrei holiday "season" *officially* ends.

Just off the top of my head, I'm curious if anyone recommends refraining from eating nuts all the way to the end of the month, or if anyone recommends eating honey on [Challah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13220/should-separating-pull-apart-challah-rolls-be-considered-a-forbidden-act-of-comp#comment21961_13220) through the last Shabbath of the month, or if some wear white throughout the month, for example. There may be other practices that are related that I'm just not thinking of as well.

Comment: I thought the refraining from eating nuts thing was only on Rosh HaShanah itself. I also thought that honey on chalah was only until Shmini Atzeres (that's what Artscroll says at the back of the machzor if I remember)

Comment: What is a "holiday season"? I can't tell you when it ends until you tell me what it is.

Comment: Some omit Tachanun through the end of the month, if that helps you.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'm using the term to refer to a lengthy season approximately a month long, though commonly extended as long as possible by the celebrants (and the exact length is the crux of the question), in which heavy focus is paid to a series of significant, and also festive, holidays, by practicing certain seasonal customs.

Comment: @SethJ So you're looking for which custom which is attached to RH YK or Sukkot starts earliest and/or ends latest?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'm using the term as loosely as possible to capture the broadest (set of) custom(s) that can be tied to Tishrei and determine the end (not the beginning - although that might also be an interesting question).

Comment: @SethJ How about Mashiv Haruach?

Comment: @DoubleAA, +1, but I don't think that's tied to the same season. In fact, I think the point of it is that it's tied to the winter season. The fact that it starts during the Tishrei season might be a hint, though.

Answer (score 3):

There is a Chabad custom ([Oztar Minhagei Chabad pg. 393](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30510&st=&pgnum=407)) to announce on Motzei Simchas Torah the [Posuk](http://beta.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8227) "ויעקב הלך לדרכו" (And Yaakov went on his way), indicating that the holiday season of Tishrie is now over, and it is now time to implement to inspiration we have received throughout the month into our everyday life. There is also a custom to make this announcement on Motzei Shabbos Breishis, and even Parshas Noach ([Otzar Minhagei Chabad pg. 400](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30510&st=&pgnum=414)).

In terms of practical customs we stop  keeping, I believe there are two things going on simultaneously; there is the period of judgment which ends on Hoshana Rabba, and then there is the general festive season of Tishrie. Thus, on Hashana Rabba is the last day we dip Challa into honey, say L'Dovid Hashem Ori and some even refrain from eating spicy/sour foods all the way till then (this is my wife's familys' custom) as it is the conclusion of the judgment.

Comment: Great answer. I'm withholding the check mark just in case anyone sources anything more general (broader than Chabad) or older. But if not, it's yours for completeness and documented support.

Comment: +1. Note that although _Chabad_ (_nusach haAri_) says "_L'David_" through _Ho"R_, most _Ashk'nazim_ say it through _Shm"A_.